# Работа утилиты df

Tags: c, c++, linux

Здравствуйте. Возможно глупый пост\вопрос, но все же..
В университете нам дали задания - найти исходники утилит (в моем случае - df , Linux), разобраться с их кодом и на их основе попытаться реализовать собственную утилиту.
Я скачала несколько разных версий исходников утилиты, но ни одна толком не хочет компилироваться с gcc, для нее тянется миллиард библиотек из coreutils, а также почему-то не все стандартные библиотеки (например - system.h) подключаются - ошибки вылазят. Куча разных "типов" неизвестно из каких хидеров используются в текстах утилиты.. В общем - сплошной мрак. 
Кто-нибудь может мне пояснить, что не так с этими исходниками я делаю - почему они не компилируются просто? 
И как можно было бы все же самой реализовать утилиту (хб часть ее возможностей)?
Одна из версии исходных кодов, которые я смотрела -
http://lingrok.org/xref/coreutils/src/df.c#ncolumns

__
По поводу ошибок с бибилиотеками - банально на первых строчках компилятор ругается на стандартную бибилотеку:
df.c:21:20: фатальная ошибка: config.h: Нет такого файла или каталога
компиляция прервана

Comment: а ридми читали? Кто будет делать `./configure && make`?

Comment: @gecube, я полный ноль в линуксе (к моему сожалению, но что поделать, если дано такое задание), но как полностью такую команду надо написать?  
gcc -o df.out df.c && ./configurate && make 
?
а если у меня нет makefile, что в нем писать?

Comment: Makefile (он пишеться с большой буквы) может быть сгенерирован скриптом конфигурации.

Comment: Кстати, если есть оба (makefile и Makefile), то `make` будет исполнять makefile (с маленькой буквы).

Comment: @alena_fox_spb дело не в том, что Вы полный ноль. Нужно всего лишь немного погуглить и разобраться (желательно, конечно, самостоятельно) в том как собирать программы. Неважно под линукс или виндовс. В данном случае - именно как собирать программы с Makefile.am. `./configure && make` нужно делать в одну команду - это собирает `config.h` по ответам пользователя и сканированию системы на предмет наличия компилятора, его версии и наличия и версий библиотек. А `make` запускает процесс компиляции файлов исходного кода. Ну, это если по-простому. Просто `gcc -o df.out df.c` в данной ситуации не пойде

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) большинство подобных утилит идут одним пакетом. Компилировать по отдельности в большинстве случаев нельзя. Редко какая утилита идет в виде одно .c файла.

2) некоторые утилиты используют свои внутренние библиотеки. В ядре линукса и окрестностях не принято, что бы каждая утилита тащила за собой все что нужно.  Размер сорцов был бы заметно выше и много дублировалось.

3)

> фатальная ошибка: config.h:

так как утилиты пишут с рассчетом на то, что они будут компилироваться/запускаться на самых разных системах, то перед компиляцией делают "конфигурацию". Специально подготовленный скрипт изучает окружение и формирует различные данные для компиляции. обычно подобный скрипт генерирует и файл config.h, куда записываются различные константы.

4) Обычно в линуксе все компилируется так

```
./configure # запустить скрипт конфигурации
make # запустить компиляцию
make install # разложить скомпилированное добро по местам.
```

в некоторых случаях существуют свои способы и обычно они описаны в файлах README или подобных.

Comment: простите за продолжение "Глупых вопросов", но как пишется (вернее, что надо писать) в скрипте конфигурации?

Comment: скрипт для конфигурации составляет тот, кто пишет программу. А что именно там будет - это зависит от программы.

Comment: @alena_fox_spb - читайте про automake и альтернативы

Answer (score 1):

вам надо изучить системный вызов fstatfs(2)